# Changing the Legend Title in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently programming in R and trying to produce an interaction chart. However, at the moment, the legend title is "sSkills". I would like to change that into "Social Skills", but by specifying "color = "Social Skills"", only a second legend is created. Help would be really appreciated.

```
intPlot <- ggplot(IntPoints2Plot, aes(sComplex, sPerform, color = sSkills, shape = sSkills, group = sSkills))

intPlot <- intPlot + geom_line(aes(linetype = sSkills))

intPlot <- intPlot + geom_point(size=5) + ylim(12,15) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=11), axis.title=element_text(size=11),legend.title=element_text(size=11),legend.text=element_text(size=11))

intPlot <- intPlot + labs(x = "Social Complexity", y = "Social Performance", color = "Social Skills")

intPlot <- intPlot + theme_apa(x.font.size = 11, y.font.size = 11, legend.use.title = T)

intPlot
```

I tried multiple answers provided in this forum, but none of these changed the "sSkills" title.

Comment: Try with adding `shape="Social Skills"`. As you map `sSkills` on both `color` and `shape` you have actually two legends which get merged into one. By setting the title only for color the legends will no longer get merged and you end up with two.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had to change it for group and linetype, but then it worked. I was actually fighting with the issue for three hours today, so you really helped me out!